# Por que essa implementação aparentemente simples do "strupr" não funciona?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

Implementação com erro no GCC:

```
    char* strupr( char *str )
    {
    while(*str) {
        *str++ = toupper(*str);
        }
    }
```

Observe que `str` é usada duas vezes no *assignment*.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Há 2 problemas: somar o ponteiro aí vai gerar um comportamento indefinido e não está retornando nada, tem que mudar a assinatura da função ou retornar algo. Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void strupr(char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        *str = toupper(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
    
int main(void) {
    char texto[] = "teste";
    strupr(texto);
    printf("%s", texto);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LGP3JU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ihqrppjh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ManualUpper.c).